# Set default value option in dropdown angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I set the default value in a dropdown, but i see always the first option selected, but if i click the dropdown the value that i want is set.

CONTROLLER

```
tantoSvagoApp.controller("ricercaAttivita", function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedRegione = regione;
});
```

HTML

```
<select class="trip dark" ng-model="selectedRegione" ng-options="regione.nome as regione.nome for regione in regioni.regionSelector">
  <option value="">TUTTE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is regione? You haven't defined it anywhere. What is regioni? You haven't defined it anywhere.

Comment: Check the answer. I have assumed a similar data array as per your HTML to demonstrate you how the things work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this code

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select  ng-options="regione.nome as regione.nome for regione in regioni.regionSelector"
           ng-model="selectedRegione"></select>

        {{ selectedRegione }}
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.selectedRegione = 'Mike';
    $scope.regioni = {
    'regionSelector':[
        { id: 1, nome: 'John'},
        { id: 2, nome: 'Rocky'},
        { id: 3, nome: 'Mike'},
        { id: 4, nome: 'Ben' }
    ]
    };
});
```

The `<option>` is created dynamically and the value for the dropdown is pre-selected by `$scope.selectedRegione = 'Mike';` which reference the `nome: 'Mike'` of the `$scope.regioni.regionSelector` array.

For simplicity and work around here is the link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zjz621tv/1/)